# AccumulatorV2 used in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a question about using accumulators in RDD and how to use them reliably.

So imagine we have the following accumulator:

```
val sc: SparkContext = //...
val accum = sc.longAccumulator("Accumulator name")
val rdd = //some rdd
rdd foreach { _ => 
    accum.add(1L)
}
```

As far as I understand it the data `RDD` represents are being splitted by partitions and each time we perform some action it tries to

```
computeOrReadCheckpoint(split: Partition, context: TaskContext)
```

for each partition.

So in case we already compute one partition fully we update the accumulator value on the driver side. But after that the executor containing this partition crashes, but the `RDD` was not checkpointed yet.

So the partition is recomputed from scratch. So I expect the accumulator is updated twice for these records.

Is such a scenario possible?